# Link any subdomain to a different path than the www-path in nginx conf-file

Tags: nginx, domain, subdomain

Example:

> http://example.com

and

> http://www.example.com

are linked to the path (it's their root)

> /var/www

I want that any other subdomain (like test.example.com or 1234.example.com) is linked automatically (without defining the subdomain as server_name in a conf-file) to /var/www/pathforanysub for example:

> test.example.com

and

> 1234.example.com

have the same root

> /var/www/pathforanysub

I'm very new to nginx and it would be quite cool if someone could help me..

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new `server` block, with a wildcard `server_name`.

```
server {
    server_name *.example.com;
    root /var/www/whatever;
```

Comment: This isn't working.
Instead of /var/www/pathforanysub the standard-path /var/www is loaded.

Comment: Then check your config for typos, and make sure you actually did restart nginx.